# 1min Interval Cronjobs inside CloudLinux

Tags: cloudlinux

So I got the following message from my server-administrator the other day:

> Hi ****,
>
> We hope you are doing well today.
>
> We have noticed one of your accounts was running multiple cron jobs
> with 1 minute intervals. *(Three; and I admit they could've been merge into 1. There were not 1000's of lines of code, literally no more than 35 combined)*
>
> *-snip-*
>
> On a shared hosting server, running a cron job every minute can have an adverse impact on the
> server's health and other users on the
> same server. To prevent the server from being negatively affected, we
> have modified the cron jobs as below:
>
> *-snip-*
>
> They will now run every at the above specified intervals. Please do not run any cronjob
> that has less than 15 minute intervals.
>
> Your cooperation will be much appreciated in this regard.
>
> Should you have further questions or concerns, please update this
> ticket.
>
> Best Regards,
> ****.

Does this make sense to anyone? Because I have looked to the cloudlinux documentation and it doesn't seem to make any sense:

[image: Picture from cloudlinux documentation]

[image: Picture from cloudlinux documentation]

I pay for a "semi-dedicated" server off them, and **80 available Entry Processes**. The only way *I see* this being a problem is if they load more users onto servers where they don't have the actual resources to account for those said users and their plans, because this was his "example":

> Unfortunately, we have to maintain some minimum restrictions to
> maintain the hosting quality. Imagine what might happen if 50 users
> run 150 cron jobs per minute on the server. A regular server might
> crawl.

And like I said, the only way I see that being a problem is if the users resources account for more than the server can handle.

Am I wrong to think this? I never got linked to documentation explaining his argument or anything, he just referred be to his "terms of service" and basically told me he works with it everyday and that I don't know what I am talking about.

Comment: Ummm... who did this? The hosting company? How is it that they have access to your server to make these modifications?

Comment: Yea the hosting company, but I am not sure, I have a semi-dedicated package with them, which includes a whm panel to manage my to 2 cPanel accounts that share the same resources.

Comment: I would point out the contradiction between "*Please do not run any cronjob that has less than 15 minute intervals*" and "*users should not feel restricted in any way*". And I would consider if this is the right partner for my application.

Comment: @berndbausch Yea really, and the fact it says in fine print in the CloudLinux Docs: `CageFS will cage any scripts execution done via: Cron Jobs`. So I fail to see what he was saying. I'm already planning on making the switch, but wanted to make sure I am not wrong before I post a nice review for the inconvenience this caused.

Comment: will, this is normal, server4you terminate your server in such a case if your vm makes a avg load level higher 0.5 even you get 8vcpus so, either accept that or go and use a other hoster like netcup or similar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CageFS documentation](https://docs.cloudlinux.com/cloudlinux_os_components/#cagefs) mentioning that the "user should not feel any way restricted" refers to file system and process isolation. A chroot or container. Users are not restricted in the applications and config files they install, but this does not imply anything about resource quotas.

Possibly the cron limitation is imposed by your host regardless of available capacity or your process quota. Easier to write a naïve crontab parser than doing good performance root cause analysis and capacity planning.

Read those terms of service, although almost certainly as administrators of the container host they are allowed to do this. They have a point that frequent cron jobs can be a significant load, especially in resource constrained environments. Although I wonder how enormous their oversubscription ratio is that even with a meagre quota of 100 processes they still feel the need to manage crontabs.

---

To make a distinction, you rented a container from a shared hosting provider, who uses CloudLinux Shared. Dedicated server use cases for CloudLinux exist, same as upstream RHEL or CL's own clone AlmaLinux.